# Cordova - Error installing plugin with android platform 7

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic v1 project (Cordova) and I use several plugins that work on Android platform 6.4.

When trying to add the android platform 7 or 7.1 one of the plugins generates Manifest directory error when it is installed and displays the message:

```
Failed to install '...': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C: \ Users \ ... \ ... \ POC \ platforms \ android \ AndroidManifest.xml'

 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C: \ Users \ ... \ ... \ POC \ platforms \ android \ AndroidManifest.xml'
```

If I remove only the accused plugin, I can add the platform normally and do the build, but I need this plugin to be in the project. (The plugin works on platform 6.4 but not on 7)

I found on Cordova's official site talking about a change that should be made in config.xml because the location of the manifest should be another on platform 7, but the change didn't work. (https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html)

When looking for this error, I found many people saying that Cordova plugins are not supported on platform 7 and should use platform 6.4, but I have other plugins that work correctly with version 7.

I use Cordova 8.0.0, Npm 6.0.1, Node 8.11.2 and Android Platform 7.1.0

Has anyone managed to solve this problem?